# Not all references released, 1 still live

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

I'm learning about retain and release methods for counting references in Objective-C, but Instruments says that is still living 1 reference of `MyClass`, the code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MyClass"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

@autoreleasepool {

    MyClass *obj;

    for (int i=0; i < 200000; i++){

        obj = [[MyClass alloc] init];
        [obj setSomeValue:100];

        NSLog(@"itineration %i", i);

        [obj release];
    }
}//@autoreleapool
}//main
```

### MyClass.h

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property int someValue;

@end
```

Why Instruments shows "16LiveBytes" "1#Living" "199999#Transient" "200000#Overall" in MyClass? Should be 0 right?

Comment: Why aren't you using ARC?

Comment: @CrimsonChris Maybe the OP wants more hand on with memory management.

Comment: using ARC still appearing 1 living. Not normal right?

Comment: if I look for the memory address of the remaining reference appears in blank, no address... so I'm think that is some kind of Instruments bug.

Comment: So, let's answer CrimsonChris's very important question first: why aren't you using ARC?  It's pretty hard to get into memory trouble if you just use ARC and there are very few good reasons to not use ARC.  Unless you can come up with a good reason why you're not using ARC, the correct answer here is "Use ARC."

Comment: @nhgrif I wrote the same code on another computer using ARC and still showing 1 remaining live reference in MyClass, if I look for the memory address used appears in blank.

Comment: First of all, ARC would yell about calling `release`, and second of all, the posted code isn't even complete.  The `for` loop isn't closed, and you don't show use where this code exists, how it's called exactly, etc, and you're asking us to diagnose memory allocations/deallocations.

Comment: @nhgrif I Edited and filled the full code including the missing loop close. Srry

Comment: What happens when you move the 'MyClass *obj;' declaration inside the for loop (ie as one line)?

Comment: @JasperBlues I just tried but same thing, Instruments says 1 remaining reference alive but hasn't memory address assigned, so I think it's some kind of bug. thx